# Magento 2.2.2 - Rename Sort By Options Label

Tags: magento2, sorting

On product listing page, I need to rename the label of Sort by Option `Position` to `Most Popular`.

Below are the two files responsible for sorting

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Config.php
```

In `Toolbar.php` you can see

```
$this->_availableOrder = $this->_catalogConfig->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
```

which in turn calls `getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()` from `Config.php` that returns array of available attributes to sort listing collection.

In `Config.php` it has below function where Position label is given

```
public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = ['position' => __('Position')];
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

1. To change the label do I need to extend Model/Config.php in my
   custom theme and change `$options = ['position' => __('Position')];` to  `$options = ['position' => __('My Custom label')];` ?
2. Can this be done by extending `sorter.phtml` ?
3. Can we change sort by options label from admin ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change sort by option label using Magento Translations directly through comma-separated value (.csv) file without making any changes in code.

For example, your store locale `en_US` then just add:

```
"Position","Most Popular"
```

in `app/design/frontend/VendorName/theme/i18n/en_US.csv`

Here, replace `VendorName` and `theme` with your current theme directory name.

**Note:** if your store running on production mode then you may need to deploy static content in order see changes on front-end.

Happy coding!

Comment: It means, for any kind of text/label changes throughout the site, we just need to include our custom translation file under i18n ? For example if we need to change form field names only without extending even then we could use it ?

Comment: Exactly, we can change text/label throughout the site using Magento translations. For more info: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: Its worked for me Thanks dear. I am working on magento2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I've tried different approach in Magento 2.3.5-p1. I've just used inline translation table in database.

Why? Inline translation take preference over translation files.

For example, to translate Position to New (Novedad in spanish), I executed this mysql query:

```
INSERT INTO translation (string, store_id, translate, locale, crc_string) VALUES 
('Position', '0', 'Novedad', 'es_ES', '1937236688'), 
('Position', '0', 'New', 'en_US', '1403912869')¡;
```

Keep in mind that you should calculate decimal crc32 for the string on the crc_string column.